# How do offsets work while animating images in UWP Apps?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to animate an image in the code behind such that it moves from left to right and then fades. I have code which looks like this.

MyDemoControl.xaml.cs

this.image.offset(offsetX:0, offsetY:0, duration:0)
.fade(1, duration:1)

My understanding is that OffsetX:0 and OffsetY:0 would be bottom left of the page. But I don't see this happening. I see different images positions differently. Any help in understanding offsets would be highly appreciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't see this happening. I see different images positions differently. Any help in understanding offsets would be highly appreciated ?

It looks you have used [`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.ui.animations.behaviors?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) to animate your image, OffsetX OffsetY that use to move the image to other position. The reference is the image control self rather than image parent.

So if you just set `OffsetX` `OffsetY`  as 0, the image control will not animate.